# Executing SQL Statements in spark-sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a text file which is of the following format:

```
ID,Name,Rating
1,A,3
2,B,4
1,A,4
```

and I want to find the average rating for each ID in spark. This is the code I have so far but it keeps on giving me an error:

```
val Avg_data=spark.sql("select ID, AVG(Rating) from table")
```

> ERROR: org.apache.sapk.sql.AnalysisException: grouping expressions sequence is empty, and 'table'.'ID' is not an aggregate function. Wrap '(avg(CAST(table.'Rating' AS BIGINT)) as 'avg(Rating)')' in windowing function(s).........

Comment: and what error is that ? can you update your question by adding the error message ?

Comment: @eliasah Just updated it.

Comment: Add a „group by ID“ at the end of your query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AVG()` is *an aggregation function* so you would *need a group by* too

```
val Avg_data=spark.sql("select ID, AVG(Rating) as average from table group by ID")
```

You should have `Avg_data` as

```
+---+-------+
|ID |average|
+---+-------+
|1  |3.5    |
|2  |4.0    |
+---+-------+
```

Comment: Yeah just figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer helped you then you should consider accepting it and upvoting too :) thanks @Skyhopper9

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by clause along with avg.

1.DataFrame df

```
+---+----+------+
| ID|Name|Rating|
+---+----+------+
|  1|   A|     3|
|  2|   B|     4|
|  1|   A|     4|
+---+----+------+
```

2.Registering df as temp table and writing query with GROUP BY and AVG()

```
df.registerTempTable("table")

val avg_data=spark.sql("select ID,avg(Rating) from table group by ID")

avg_data.show

+---+-----------+
| ID|avg(Rating)|
+---+-----------+
|  1|        3.5|
|  2|        4.0|
+---+-----------+
```